# How to represent sequential points from a function more economically as a Bézier curve or else?

Tags: interpolation, bezier-curve

I have written a graphics library that has a module that plots function lines.  Internally, software goes from a starting x-value to an ending x-value in steps that equal a pixel.  This produces substantially more points than necessary to faithfully represent the line.  An algorithm in the spirit of Ramer–Douglas–Peucker (but much faster) is used to reduce, for example, 248 points to 43 without a loss of accuracy.  The latter are then plotted as a polyline (see the first two images below).

The results are quite satisfactory given the objectives of the library.  Reducing the points needed by 87% decreases the size of SVGs and significantly improves image generation performance.  Wanting to push some optimizations further, I attempted curve fitting.  The third image below shows the application of the algorithm (from "Graphics Gems" text) that fits one or more cubic Bezier curves to a polyline.  [fit-curve](https://github.com/soswow/fit-curve) npm package was used.  The fit line in the image was generated with an error setting of 1 and consists of 16 coordinates.

Having 16 coordinates is certainly an improvement over 43, but there are two main issues.  **First**, for some functions the fitted line has about as many coordinates as the input coordinates it is meant to simplify.  And **second**, fitting is time consuming.  On my machine performing 1000 fittings for the line presented takes 2 seconds.  The library currently can generate 10,000 graphs shown in Figure 2 in about 1.2 seconds.  Adding 20 seconds of fitting processing obviously makes no sense.

Is there anything that I am missing?  Is it possible to mathematically derive the Bezier curves?  For example, would it make sense to break the line below into two segments (i.e., from origin and down and from origin and up) and try to fit one quadratic Bezier into each segment?  When I play with Bezier curves manually, I get an intuitive sense that this may be possible.

**Here is another way to frame the problem.**  The following are the first six coordinates for the polyline in  figure 2: `[20.9, 284.1], [27, 263], [34, 241.3], [41, 222.4], [48, 205.9], [54, 193.7], [60, 183.1], [66, 173.9]`.  I can use the following Bezier command as part of the path tag to represent that section almost the same (while using half the characters): `M 20.9 284.1 C 32.3 244.6, 43.4 208.6, 66 173.9`.  I would like, if possible, to non-iteratively (i.e., deterministically) compute that Bezier segment.

**Figure 1:** Dots that Compose a Function Line

[image: Function "line" as dots]

**Figure 2:** Function Line Plotted from Dots

[image: Function line from dots]

**Figure 3:** Bezier Curve Fitted to Dots

[image: Bezier Curve fitted to Dots]

Comment: See also the classic paper https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/964967.801153

Comment: I mention in my question that I am using a fitting algorithm from 1990 "Graphics Gems" text that iteratively produces Bezier curves that do fit my data accurately.  From a standpoint of just having a solution, there is one.  But, I've outlined the issues with this approach: it takes too long computationally and sometimes the number of Bezier control points exceeds the data that needs to be fitted, rendering the solution moot.  Here's the source for that algorithm: https://github.com/erich666/GraphicsGems/blob/master/gems/FitCurves.c

Answer (score 0):

In mathematical terms, you’re trying to approximate your original function by a string of cubic polynomials (which you choose to represent in Bézier form).

Approximation by polynomials is an old and rich area of mathematics, so you have many techniques to choose from. I will mention two, specifically:

1. On a given segment of your original function, you could choose four points, and interpolate with a cubic polynomial. This is called **Lagrange interpolation**.
2. On a given segment of your original function, you could choose two points and their corresponding derivative (tangent) values, and interpolate these with a cubic polynomial. This is called **Hermite cubic interpolation**.

You can Google these two terms to get started.

For both techniques, there are formulas for the errors involved in the approximations. These formulas typically involve fourth derivatives of your original function, which you will need to estimate (by sampling, typically).

Comment: There appears to be a disconnect in the problem that I am trying to solve and what you are suggesting.  I am `not` trying to approximate a function - the library already receives it as a subroutine that accepts x and spits out y.  The goal is that of re-representation of these x,y points more economically.  For example, here are six x-y line pairs: `[[95, 284.2], [99, 248.7], [103, 219.5], [107, 195.9], [111, 177.6 ], [115, 163.7]] `.  I can use the  shorter SVG path command `M 95 284.2 C 99.6 243.6, 103.7 203, 115 163.7` to represent them faithfully.  Is there an exact math for that?

Comment: Naturally, a quadratic Bezier would be preferred, because it is shorter.

Comment: I’d say that you are trying to approximate a function. The thing that receives x and returns y is the “function”. The svg path is an approximation of this function. If you’re really lucky, the svg path will represent your function exactly, with an approximation error of zero.

Comment: We seem to be splitting hairs.  SVG that is plotted now is not an approximation.  It includes exact values produced by the subroutine and graphed as a polyline.  If I want to replace groups of these exact points with a pithier spec, then for each group I need to derive a "shape"/(or "function") plotting of which would include the skipped points.  Within SVG such a shape can only be expressed as an (1) arc or (2) Bezier curve.  Going in the direction of Lagrange or Hermite interpolation takes me nowhere, because  in the end I still have to use Beziers.

Comment: I have a solution drawing on this piece: https://www.jimherold.com/computer-science/best-fit-bezier-curve.  Using good 'ole least-squares works well for fitting a cubic bezier into a set of coordinates.  The key appears to be splitting the dataset into groups that are fittable.  I am working on that right now.  So far, for the example above, I only need three cubic beziers to represent the line without distortions.  And, if groups are picked right, there is no need to iterate, so the solution is also fast.